# Find combinations of a list of sets

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, combinations

I'm using python 2.7. Given a list of sets, is there any quick and efficient way to generate the combinations? Input sets always have one item in each set and output sets all have length of 2 
From:

```
[set(['item1']), set(['item2']), set(['item3'])]
```

To:

```
[set(['item1','item2']), set(['item2','item3']), set(['item3','item1'])]
```

Comment: look at the `itertools` module

Comment: This needs to be a lot clearer. Can you give an example where the input sets don't all have length 1? Does the output need to be in a certain order? Why do the output sets all have length 2?

Comment: @AlexHall Sorry. That's wasn't part of my consideration. Never thought of that =x. However, Input sets always have one item in each set and output sets all have length of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the elements in your list of sets are all 1-element sets, the combinations that you are looking for are just the 2-element subsets of the union of those sets. You can obtain them like this:

```
>>> import itertools

>>> sets = [set(['item1']), set(['item2']), set(['item3'])]
>>> elements = set()
>>> for s in sets: elements.update(s)
```

thus

```
>>> elements
{'item1', 'item2', 'item3'}
```

And then, just this:

```
>>> pairs = [set(combo) for combo in itertools.combinations(elements,2)]
>>> pairs
[{'item1', 'item2'}, {'item1', 'item3'}, {'item2', 'item3'}]
```

Comment: Thanks! This exactly want I wanted. Thanks for explaining too.

Answer (score 1):

As John pointed out `itertools` might be of help. Here's a quick example:

```
import itertools as it
sets = [set(range(0, 3)), set(range(2, 5)), set(range(4, 7))]
comb = list(it.combinations(sets, r=2))
comb
```

output: `[({0, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}), ({0, 1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}), ({2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6})]`

Then create an intersection in each iteration:

```
comb_sets = [a.intersection(b) for a, b in comb]
comb_sets
```

output: `[{2}, set(), {4}]`